# vs 2013 express does not create an exe file

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I hope you can help with this problem. I have installed vs2013 express on my Windows 7 PC and have tried a simple 'hello world' console project to check the installation. When I build the project the program reports no errors or warnings and builds successfuly, however when I try to run it I get the message: "test1.exe is not recognised as an internal or external command" and the program does not run.(test1 is the name of the project).
I tried to search for the exe file, as there is nothing in the debug folder and basically, no exe file is created by visual studio 2013 express anywhere on my c drive. I tried a couple more attempts at different, simple projects, with the same result. No exe file is created.

Comment: Post the full build output, please. Also, did your antivirus report anything? Some might just delete "suspicious" exe

Comment: Yeah, virus scanner probably. They don't like it if applications start creating or modifying executables. You'll probably have to configure some exceptions in your scanner.

Comment: Which version of Express did you install? Different versions are intended to build different types of application.

Comment: I am using  2013 Express for windows desktop and have tried disabling my antivirus temporarily, but still get the same result- no exe file created. 

Build output is as follows 
1>------ Build started: Project: test1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I would try setting the build output to verbose and and see if you get more information

Comment: Thanks Ade. I will try that a bit later today and get back to you with the results.

Comment: Hi. I tried what you said and it came up with 1>Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Users\Bill\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (entry point):
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationError)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
1>Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).

Comment: Hi. Add to previous comment: couldn't put complete output as it's too long for comments. I dont know if output means anything to anyone,I'm not well up on debugging techniques.

Comment: I dont know whether this helps but I tried vs 2012 express as well and got exactly the same - no exe file created?

Comment: Hi again. I have now tried installing windows 8 (trial version) and still get the same problem, no exe file in vs 2013 express. I have not changed any of the settings in vs 2013 at all but it looks like it must be something to do with settings. I'm completely stumped!

Comment: SOLVED at last! I decided to try again, installed vs 2013 express-still same no exe file. Tried installing vs 2012 express again but, to save time, didn't uninstall vs 2013 express first so ended up wiith both installed on my machine. Lo and behold vs 2012 express now works! I've no idea how but thought I'd let everyone know. Thanks again.